# on your desk or at your desk?

Tags: prepositions

Please clarify the usage of right preposition on or at.

For example: That paper is **on** your desk.

or That paper is **at** your desk.

Comment: It has to be **on** your desk.

Comment: @Durga, not necessarily (see my answer below)

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I agree. But, still I would say **on** is more specific. But, if  you just want to convey that it is at the desk and not the specifics, then i guess at can be used too

Comment: @Durga being specific (and correct) requires more knowledge (or more tidiness than I have), e.g: Laptop - on or (in bag) under; Book - on or (on shelf) beside.

Comment: In my experience, objects are *on* a desk (if they're physically on it), and people are *at* a desk (if they're seated in front/back of it, depending on your point of view).

Answer (score 7):

The prepositions

- *at* implies spatial location, or directional.
- *on* implies vertically atop.

at:

- He is *at* home.
- She is at work.
- They are at Walmart.
- People are looking at us.

at (idiomatic)

- While we're at it, I might as well remind you to flush the dang toilet every time.
- I am hacking at the problem now.

on:

- She is sitting on the chair.
- We are on the hilltop.
- The cat is on the fridge.

on (idiomatically on top or over)

- I am on the problem now. Don't worry.
- He is speaking on the history of the Roman empire.
- The television channel comes on air at 5 am.

Therefore, see the difference ...

- She is sitting at my desk.
- She is sitting on my desk.
- The boy is speaking at his mother's desk.
- The boy is yelling at his mother's dog.
- The boy is yelling on his mother's desk.
- The boy is speaking on his trip to New Zealand last week.

The paper is {on/at} your desk

- Idiomatic use of desk = a virtual work space, especially in news reporting or editorial endeavours.

  - The news desk of Larry King. The latest edition of today's events is at Larry's desk.
  - Please make sure any submission for drafts of your novels are at the editor's desk before 2016/01/31.
  - The paper on the advantages of CMOS analogue design should be at the conference submission desk by noon Aug 1, 2016.
- Physical desk

  - He found the paper at his desk. I have no idea if he found it on, under or beside his desk. But it is on his desk now.

Today, Harry will be speaking on his desk being burned to ashes last week. He intends to sit on his desk when he speaks on his no longer existent old desk. He will be telling us on his old desk, like as though he is telling on us to our boss. He will be telling on his old desk about all the secrets it held.

Since he will be targeting at his old desk, he might as well be telling on the hatred he thinks his desk had on him. Since he will be at his old desk, he might as well be on his old desk, on their mutual love-hate relationship with each other, while sitting on his new desk and delighted at his new desk.

In fact, he was at his new desk this morning writing his speech on a piece of paper. That paper is now on his desk. He plans to submit it to CNN's news desk hoping they would publish it. But we know it won't be on CNN, because such a silly paper will never be found at CNN's news desk.

Comment: Does *on* imply "vertically atop" in *There is a fly on the wall*?

Comment: *On the wall* is a nearly an idiomatic use. When you look at a notice board tacked with all kinds of memos, and you can't see your memo - then someone yells at you to say, "Your memo is ***underneath*** the poster. Someone has tacked a poster ***on top*** of other people's memos." Despite that the notice board being vertical **on** the vertical wall.

Answer (score 5):

The correct usage is:

That paper is *on* your desk.

The preposition *at* is used in a slightly different situation:

You should be *at* your desk during office hours.

Comment: To clarify, people are at their desks.  Objects are on or in those people's desks.

Answer (score 2):

In American English we would almost always say

> The paper is on your desk.

and *on* is used when we refer to something being in contact with the surface of an object. This often means *on top of* a surface, such as a desk. This can also refer to a vertical surface, as in *The fly is on the wall*.

*At* is used to specify a location as a *point in space*. It just means *where your desk is*. It does not mean *on top of* your desk, like *on your desk* would usually mean. We might say *the guest is at your desk*. Or maybe *the umbrella is at your desk*. Technically, we could say *the paper is at your desk* but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The usage of on / at is more clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

*On* is most likely right in this case but not necessarily. If it's on the bookshelf next to your desk, and you're in another room, *at* your desk is just enough information for your colleague to know how long it will take to fetch it. If it's in the desk drawer, *at*, *in* and *under* are all more appropriate than *on*. It would be unusual to use anything other than *on* for an item to which it was definitely applicable, or could be assumed to be applicable, such as a keyboard. If you said *on* when it wasn't literally true, the only person who would be bothered is someone you'd sent to look for it.

I'm used to southern British English, some relevant influences here may be engineering terminology, and large open plan offices ("at my desk" would be equivalent to "in my office" or even "in my cubicle")

Comment: In ordinary use, the only thing AT someone's desk is the person who uses it.  Everything else should be more location-specific.  The paper is on the desk, the stapler is in the desk, the computer tower is under the desk.  For a paper to be AT a desk would be highly unnatural usage.

Comment: @StevenLittman, maybe it's the variant of English I'm used to or maybe in my field we leave more, bigger items at our desks, but in my experience "at" isn't unusual. I agree that for the specific example of a paper, either "on"  or "in" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Chris H--it would be helpful if you'd identify which variety of English you are used to.  It seems to me that the guideline I stated is fairly basic and therefore I would think it was universal.

Comment: @Steven, edited in (S. UK), also note about why I might be familiar with this use.